# Gradle Sync failed in android studio 3.0

Tags: android, gradle

I am getting all these errors in gradle sync. I have gone through almost all answers related to this error but none of it helped in my situation.

```
Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debug/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugAndroidTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.

Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@release/compileClasspath': Could not resolve com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0.][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/C7fnI.png
```

Comment: Could you describe background of your action? Is it new project or downloaded? Did you downloaded new Android Studio or upgraded?

Comment: I made a new project on newly downloaded android studio